# Working with DIalogs in Fragments

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

In my application, I have the Activity and several Fragments (Activity works as Controller and Fragments - as views)

In some of Fragments I need to show AlertDialogs and ProgressDialogs, Activity can change current Fragment.

My problem is: activity can receive broadcasts and C2DM notifications, and when I created AlertDialog, Activity can change fragment, but Dialog stays. So when user clicks on some buttons, app crashes.

DIalogFragments works like a simple Dialog.

Have I dismiss dialog manually or check if fragment is active? Is there any built-in tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I might be missing something, no code etc to go by but...

Secondly: maybe you shouldn't be using dialoges? Seems like a cumbersome user interface. Just use fragments for those as well? Though you say you are using DialogFragments so maybe you've already thought about that and use them as "regular" fragments already.

Thirdly: Dismiss the dialogs when the fragment that showed is removed/hidden then? Use the onStop() callback for example in the fragment or a more central place where you are perhaps saving the currently showing fragment and deciding to display a new one.
Dismiss the dialog by calling ´dismiss´ on the Dialog object or Fragment or `dismissDialog` in the Activity.

See dismissing dialog: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#DismissingADialog

You can still call dismiss on those DialogFragments.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.htm